# What is the meaning of "to color copy"?

Tags: word-meaning

I have this text, but I cannot find the answer for my question. Can anyone of you guys help me?

> The exercise is to ask students **to color copy** their own wedding
>   photograph, that of their parents, or an anonymous wedding picture,
>   and to write a one-page fiction inspired by the image.

Comment: What is your guess as to what “color copying” a photo might be?

Comment: The sentence is full of mistakes. Were you aware of that? Where did it come from?

Comment: It is an awkward way of saying "to make a color copy" (as opposed to a black and white copy). The expectation probably is that they will use a color photocopier.

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers. The text I extract belongs to a book about writing exercises for authors.

Answer (score 1):

"**Color copying**" means you have a colored paper (that might be a photo, a painting or...), you scan it into a printer and then print out one or several copies of this paper (in color mode).

As far as I can understand, in this exercise students are supposed to make a copy of their own wedding photograph (and some other pictures). These copies should be **colored**, not black and white.